# How can I switch between two windows in appium ( python )

Tags: python, selenium, appium, windows-application-driver

I'm trying to run a test that opens a new window in run time
I have a button in my main app that opens a new window with a different name
I try to use:

```
desired_caps["app"] = 'myappname'
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
        desired_capabilities= desired_caps)
driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click()
#after click on this a new window opens with this name, "Confirmation"
driver.switch_to_window("Confirmation")
```

I also, try to write in a different way:

```
webdriver.switch_to.SwitchTo.window(self,"Confirmation")
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you opened a new window. You're trying to switch to a window that isn't open yet?

Try:

```
driver.get('http://website.com')
```

Comment: when I click on the delete button a popup YES or NO window shown to me and this window is not a child of my main window so I don't have access to this window to click on yes

Comment: HTML popup or system dialog box?

Comment: my app is running in windows. its base is on QT and C++.

Comment: Post image of the popup. Is it system (Windows popup?) or website popup?

Comment: it's windows popup

Answer (score 0):

To Switch between two windows in windows base application we can use...

```
windows = self.driver.window_handles
self.driver.switch_to.window(windows[0])
```

by this snippet of code, we can switch between two windows that open in each other.
usually Yes or No windows open in the main window and you can switch to that window by this.